# multiplication principle and permutation rule; when to use what

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

Problem: You have CDs of which n1= # of classical, n2= # of rocks, n3= # of pop. How many ways can we place the CDs on a rack but keep the genres together?

**The Answer is:**
Because there are n1 ways to order classical, n1i (n1 factorial), similarly we have n2i, n3i. And because there are 3 different ways to order classical, rock and pop, we want to multiply by 3 factorial. The answer is (3!)*(n1!)*(n2!)*(n3!)

**MY QUESTION:** In this problem, the order matters, but it doesn't specify which genre should come first or second, or third. But since **the order matters**, can we still apply the permutation rule?
For instance, r = 3 since there are 3 ways to order 3 genres. We can say the total # of ways to place the CDs and keeping the genres together are:

Permutation(n1 and r=3*Permutation(n2 and r=2)*Permutation(n3=r=1)

Since the problem didn't specify which genre will come first or second, we don't know which of n1,n2, or n3 will get r=3 or 2 or 1, so I understand this way isn't correct, but I'm struggling to understand when to use Permutation rule and when to use simply just multiplication principle.

**Experiment:** I assigned random numbers to n1,n2,n3 (n1=5,n2=6, n3=7) and tried both ways and the correct way ( 3!*(n1!)*(n2!)*(n3!)) shows a lot more ways then using the permutation rule.
3!(5!)(6!)(7!) vs. (5!/2!)*(6!/4!)*(7!/6!)

Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not understanding what the $(\frac{5!}{2!})(\frac{6!}{4!})(\frac{7!}{6!})$ was supposed to represent... that looks like you took only three of the five available classical albums... lined those up... then followed that by two of the six available rock albums, lined those up after, and then one of the seven available pop albums...

Comment: You are trying to use and assign some "$r$" value here which is wholly out of place and unneeded.  You seem to be remembering a formula along the lines of $P(n,r)=\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$... but are using that where not appropriate.  That is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) and counts the number of ways of arranging $r$ items in a row when taken from a set with $n$ items in it...  Here, we are wanting to use *all* of the available albums of each type... not just some of them.

Comment: I recommend ignoring all formulas you think you've learned and go with the basics a bit longer... just raw multiplication principle.  You look at the shelf and you have spaces for all $(n_1+n_2+n_3)$ of the albums.  You look and you pick one of the albums to put in the first position.  Once having picked an album for that first position, you pick which other album of that type should follow, then which other of the same type should follow that, etc... until having used all of that type.  You then pick which album to place next and then place all others of that album type, and so on...

Comment: Thanks for chiming in @JMoravitz ! As you said, I think I should ignore the formulas and just go with the basics. Trying a few more practice problems with just using the basic multiplication principle will help me understand the concept better.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: For r = 3 there are 6 ways to order the genres. aka 3!. You have rock pop classical , rock classical pop , pop rock classical, pop classical rock , classical pop rock, classical rock pop